# Retrieve multiple tables with snmp4j TableUtils

Tags: snmp, snmp4j

Documentation for snmp4j TableUtils implies the getTables method can be used to retrieve more than one table. Anyone know how to use it in that manner. Just not intuitive for me. I'm wondering if i just put in the columns for table 1 and table 2 in the OID argument and the table util will be able to seperate them all out and i'll just have to distinguish them in the list of TableEvents (rows) that are returned?

http://www.snmp4j.org/doc/org/snmp4j/util/TableUtils.html

Answer (score 1):

I have tried the same situation as you have posted here. While trying out OIDs from different tables i reached the following conclusion and i'm nt sure whether its the way which they have intended. The VariableBinding[] we get as an output will contain result in the order in which we are passing the OIDs into the array and thereby we can match the input and output.

For eg  input - new OID[".1.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.2", ".1.3.6.1.2.1.25.4.2.1.2"];
        output -new VariableBinding["1.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.2.1=somevalue",       "1.3.6.1.2.1.25.4.2.1.2.1=System Idle Process"];
                new VariableBinding["1.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.2.2=somevalue", null];
                .
                .
                .

Hope it was some use for you.

Regards

Ajin

Comment: Its been such a long time since I've been working on this. I don't remember if this was my solution. +1 for your good intentions :)